# JavaMail on Oracle 12.2 Database cannot load providers

Tags: java, windows, oracle, jakarta-mail, tls1.2

I am attempting to install the latest JavaMail after installing Oracle Database 12.2.  JavaMail was working fine on a prior database server.  It not working and I'm at my wit's end.  Here's the error trace:

```
DEBUG: not loading system providers in <java.home>/lib
DEBUG: not loading optional custom providers file: /META-INF/javamail.providers
DEBUG: can't load default providers file/META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {}
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {}
DEBUG: not loading optional address map file: /META-INF/javamail.address.map
Exception in thread "Root Thread" javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException: No
provider for imap
        at javax.mail.Session.getProvider(Session.java:289)
        at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:363)
        at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:343)
        at javax.mail.Session.getStore(Session.java:329)
        at MailHandlerImpl.connectToServerSSL(MailHandler:453)
```

As you can see, it's not able to load the providers.  I have determined that the javax.mail.jar file in the JavaMail folder does, in fact, contain the providers file.

Here's what I've done (I changed the company name to CUSTOMER and the Oracle username to OracleUser but otherwise these are the exact statements):

## STEP 1: Install software

1. Installed Oracle Database 12.2
2. Java:

   - Installed jdk1.8.0_181 in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
   - Downloaded Javamail 1.6.1
   - Copied Javax.mail.jar to c:\JavaMail
   - Downloaded jaf-1.1.1
   - Installed it in c:\jaf-1.1.1
3. Environment variables:

   - CLASSPATH     .;C:\JavaMail\javax.mail.jar
   - JAVA_HOME     C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
   - JAVAMAIL_JAR      C:\JavaMail\javax.mail.jar
   - LD_LIBRARY_PATH   %JAVA_HOME%\lib
   - ORACLE_HOME       D:\app\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1
   - PATH          .;C:\JavaMail;C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;D:\app\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;D:\app\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\opatch;D:\app\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\perl\bin;%SystemRoot%\system32;... plus rest of the path

## STEP 2: Create ACLs

4. Create ACLs for SMTP:

   ```
   BEGIN
     DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.create_acl (
       acl          => 'mail_for_oracleuser.xml', 
       description  => 'Oracle User access to Customer email', 
       principal    => 'ORACLEUSER',
       is_grant     => TRUE, 
       privilege    => 'connect',
       start_date   => SYSTIMESTAMP,
       end_date     => NULL);
   END;

   BEGIN
     DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.assign_acl (
       acl => 'mail_for_oracleuser.xml',
       host => 'MAILSERVER.CUSTOMER.LOCAL', 
       lower_port => 25,
       upper_port => NULL); 
   END;
   ```
5. Create ACLs for IMAP

   ```
   BEGIN
     DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.CREATE_ACL(
           acl => 'mail.xml',
           description => 'MAIL ACL',
           principal   => 'ORACLEUSER',
           is_grant    => true,
           privilege   => 'connect');

     DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ADD_PRIVILEGE(
           acl => 'mail.xml',
           principal => 'ORACLEUSER',
           is_grant  => true,
           privilege => 'resolve');

     DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.ASSIGN_ACL(
           acl  => 'mail.xml',
           host => 'mail.customer.org');
   END;

   BEGIN
     DBMS_NETWORK_ACL_ADMIN.DROP_ACL(
        acl => '/sys/acls/customer_email_server_wallet.xml');
   END;

   BEGIN
     dbms_network_acl_admin.create_acl(
           'customer_email_server_wallet.xml', 
           'Customer Email Server SSL Wallet ACL',
        'ORACLEUSER', 
            TRUE, 
            'use-client-certificates');

     dbms_network_acl_admin.assign_wallet_acl(
           'customer_email_server_wallet.xml', 
            'file:d:/wallet');
   END;
   ```

## STEP 3: Grant Permissions

```
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', '10.10.80.10:143', 'connect,resolve' );
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', '10.10.80.10:993', 'connect,resolve' );
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', '10.10.80.21:143', 'connect,resolve');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', '10.10.80.21:993', 'connect,resolve');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', 'mail.customer.org', 'connect,resolve,send');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', 'MAIL.CUSTOMER.ORG', 'connect,resolve,send');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', 'mail.customer.org', 'resolve');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', '[https://mail.customer.org]', 'connect, resolve');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.net.SocketPermission', '*', 'connect,resolve,send');

call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.util.PropertyPermission', '*', 'read,write');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.lang.RuntimePermission', 'getClassLoader','');

call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '*', 'read,write');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', '*', 'execute');

call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'c:\javamail\javax.mail.jar', 'read');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'D:\app\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\lib\activation.jar', 'read');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('ORACLEUSER', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\jaf-1.1.1\activation.jar', 'read');

call dbms_java.grant_permission('PUBLIC', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'c:\javamail\javax.mail.jar', 'read');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('PUBLIC', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'D:\app\Oracle\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\lib\activation.jar', 'read');
call dbms_java.grant_permission('PUBLIC', 'SYS:java.io.FilePermission', 'C:\jaf-1.1.1\activation.jar', 'read');
```

EDIT:  I noticed that activation.jar was not listed in the classpath.  I added that, rebooted the server and received exactly the same results.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Did you follow the steps in [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#securityManager)?  This includes adding activation debugging and security manager tracing which you should include in your question.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.  In response to the JavaMail FAQ, yes, I've followed all of the steps as carefully as possible.  The DEBUG output is listed at the top of this page and shows that it cannot load any of the providers, nor can it load the address map from the META-INF section of the javax.mail.jar file.  The information displayed above in step 3 shows the permissions I have granted to the user (and to PUBLIC) with regard to reading the JAR. We have replicated the previous working setup where the only difference is Oracle 12.2 instead of 12.1, but we get the exact same error.